# Arduino: Conexao bluetooth, e armazenamento de dados

Tags: c++, arduino

Sou iniciante e estou com alguns projetos em mente, gostaria de saber se é possivel ligar o celular ao arduino e fazer com q uma aplicação passe alguns dados para alguma memoria ligada ao arduino e dps outro dispositivo seja capaz de pegar essas informaçoes... Será q é possivel fazer algo do tipo???

Comment: Bom imagino que você também esteja começando no StackOverFlow. Aqui você precisa detalhar mais o que você quer, e também mostrar isso com mais precisão através de códigos, imagens ou esboços da sua ideia para que nos possamos ajudar...

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, mas a minha pergunta foi sim por que eu realmente não tenho base nenhuma de arduino, só tenho algumas ideias, e queria saber se dá pra fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, isso é possível: ( Vou dar uma explanada por cima, porque vc no caso solicitou apenas a possibilidade)

Ligar o celular ao Arduino:
 -  Por Bluetooth: - Você deverá usar o MIT App inventor para fazer seu app para Android e preparar seu codigo em arduino para tomar ações assim que receber as informações do celular através da porta serialdo shield HC05 ou HC06 (Bluetooth).(Busque no youtube acender led por arduino e android)
 - Por Http (web) - Você deverá usar o shield Ethernet, onde lá dentro você desenvolverá a pagina em HTTP para assim que receba o link de referência , ex: `http://192.168.0.200/?acendaled` e `http://192.168.0.200/?apagaled` ele receba na porta serial `?acendaled` e `?apagaled` e execute as funções dentro do programa conforme você quer associar tipo assim que ele receber ?acendeled acende o LED na porta 11:

```
if(readString.indexOf("?acendeled") >0) {
           DigitalWrite(11,HIGH);
```

A vantagem de usar o Ethernet Shield é que você pode executar de qualquer celular, sugiro usar botões e tabelas responsivas do bootstrap porque se adapta ao tamanho da tela.

Espero ter ajudado, []'s